# How can I move this block of text using a custom Angular directive?

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to move a block of text up or down when arrows are pressed. I am having troubles getting my directive to change its CSS values when the buttons are pressed.

Here is my HTML:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.2.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.22/angular.js" data-semver="1.2.22"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="subtitle.js"></script>
  </head>
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
<h1>Move Text up or down</h1>
<subtitle class="sub" pos="position">This will move when buttons are pressed</subtitle>
<br>
  Position={{position}}
  <br>
  <br>
  <p style="color:red">Click buttons to move text up or down</p>

  <i class="fa fa-chevron-up" ng-click="inc()"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-chevron-down" ng-click="dec()"></i>
  </body>

</html>
```

Here is my directive:

```
angular.module('mSystem')
    .directive('subtitle', function () {

        "use strict";

        var
            scope = {
                pos: "="
            },
            restrict = 'AE',

            link = function($scope, $element, $attrs){
                $scope.$watch('pos', function () {
                        console.log("position is: "+$scope.pos);
                        $element.css('{top:'+$scope.pos+'px;position:relative;!important}');
                        $attrs.style="top:'+$scope.pos+'px;position:relative;!important'";

                });
            };

        return {
            scope: scope,
            link: link,
            restrict: restrict
        };
    });
```

and here is my app:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
 $scope.position=20;
 $scope.inc=function(){
   $scope.position+=1;

 }
 $scope.dec=function(){
  console.log('subtracted');
   $scope.position-=1;
 }
});
```

I have created an angular.js plunker here: http://plnkr.co/o99x2Z

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for changing the CSS is a bit different. Try this:

```
$element.css('top', $scope.pos + 'px');
```

[Updated plunker](http://plnkr.co/uMAT3b2QHxmBAPuBZgMX)

Answer (score 0):

You are passing a string to the `$element.css()`, use an **Object** instead:

```
$element.css({ top: $scope.pos+'px', position: 'relative;!important' });
```

**[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/56JdQ62NNLenqJ9uRUJr?p=preview)**